Minimum cost path connecting exactly K vertices
I came across a situation in real life that maps to this optimization problem:

Given a fully connected, undirected, weighted graph with $N \ge K$ vertices, find the simple path connecting exactly $K$ vertices with the minimum cost1

My understanding is that when $K=N$ this is the Traveling Salesman Problem. I was initially expecting to find a best approach in the literature, but despite my efforts I was unable to.
Generally for this problem $N \sim 10^2$. Ideally I would like:

An exact solution2, if $K \ll N$
A good approximation otherwise

I would need my own implementation. Which algorithms / heuristics should I be looking at?

1. Intended as sum of weights on the edges
2. I believe Held-Karp would work for this, but I'm not sure whether there are better approaches I'm not aware of.

I assume you've looked at the Wikipedia page on the TSP, including algorithms based on ILP?

What's your definition for "fully connected" ?

@JimN, there is an edge between every pair of vertices.

@D.W., Yes, I had looked into that early on, then went on many tangents while researching, I'll review it now. ILP is not a field I'm very familiar with. I have two main concerns: first, I am not sure I understand how to extend the full formulation to my subproblem for non-DP algorithms like Held-Karp; second, I know there exist multiple industrial grade solvers for ILP problems using algorithms like simplex / branch & bound + advanced heuristics, but I'm not sure how well a naïve implementation would do, and I'm not sure how to formulate the problem in OR terms.

There is a 2-approximation for this problem. The problem is known as $k$-TSP, or sometimes Quota TSP, and is a variant of the prize-collecting TSP; specifically when the prize is unit and the penalty is set to 0.

Thanks @PålGD, yes, that looks about right. I had seen the PC-TSP problem, but failed to recognize the formulation you described. Do I understand correctly, you are saying there is an algorithm that approximates the solution by a worst-case factor of 2? If you had to implement a solution for this without using an external library, would implementing a version of simplex + branch and cut be the way to go, or am I better off some other way?

Is the graph metric/Euclidean?

Good question. Correct me if I'm wrong, a graph is considered Euclidean if the edges length satisfies the triangular inequality, i.e. the closest path from one node to another is never through a third edge, correct? In my case the distances are quite arbitrary so I can add that constraint, but I would then need to validate my data, the complexity of which I'm not sure
